@container queries don't change grid-template-columns value
Having a page where we require that if container width is below view size then change 5 columns into 2 columns and trying below:


.list {
  background-color: grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.letter {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  justify-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  color: white;
}

@container (max-width:500px) {
  .list {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .letter {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
<div class="list">
  <div class="letter">A</div>
  <div class="letter">B</div>
  <div class="letter">C</div>
  <div class="letter">D</div>
  <div class="letter">E</div>
</div>



But it doesn't work; checked in Chrome and Firefox in Ubuntu.

I could be wrong but I'm thinking that you can't actually style the the container with @container only this children. A container query will apply styles to elements based on the size of the nearest ancestor with a containment context.

Yeppers - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WNBZJQv

I think you are one container 'out'.
This snippet introduces a wrapper which is set to be a 'container' so the .list element has a container to be tested.


.wrapper {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.list {
  background-color: grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.letter {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  justify-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  color: white;
}

@container (max-width:500px) {
  .list {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  .letter {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
    <div class="letter">B</div>
    <div class="letter">C</div>
    <div class="letter">D</div>
    <div class="letter">E</div>
  </div>
</div>




oh. this works. but when I write (max-width>=500px) nothing works. is >= is not valid expression for container queries?

It is but I think your issue is the max-width as (width >= 500px) works fine
